# when mocked method with ref parameter is used, assert MustHaveHappened fails

Tags: unit-testing, assert, fakeiteasy

Im using FakeItEasy to mock methods for unit tests. One of method (using REF parameter - **maybe this is important**) saves data in database, so it's mocked as 'Does Nothing'

```
A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Save(ref mwbeUserData)).DoesNothing();
```

. But in this situation last assert fails

```
A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Save(ref mwbeUserData)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
```

with error:

```
Assertion failed for the following call:
    MobileWallet.Common.DAL.IMwbeUserRepository.Save(<NULL>)
  Expected to find it exactly once but found it #0 times among the calls:
    1: MobileWallet.Common.DAL.IMwbeUserRepository.Get(userName: \"AAA\")
    2: MobileWallet.Common.DAL.IMwbeUserRepository.Save(user: MobileWallet.Common.Repository.MwbeUserData)
```

Full code of test

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddUser_MwbeUserObjectReturned()
{
    //Arrange

    MwbeUserRegistrationIn userRegistrationIn = new MwbeUserRegistrationIn()
    {
        BirthDate = DateTime.Today,
        Email = "www@wp.pl",
        FirstName = "Adam",
        SecondName = "Ada2",
        UserName = "AAA"
    };

    //mock mockedNotificationService and related: 
    INotificationService mockedNotificationService = A.Fake<INotificationService>();
    //TODO: create notofication service

    //mock IMwbeUserRepository and related
    IMwbeUserRepository mockedUserRepository = A.Fake<IMwbeUserRepository>();

    MwbeReturnData<MwbeUserData> mwbeReturnData = new MwbeReturnData<MwbeUserData>(MwbeResponseCodes.NotFound);          

    MwbeUserData mwbeUserData = mwbeReturnData.Data;

    A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Get(userRegistrationIn.UserName)).Returns(mwbeReturnData);
    A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Save(ref mwbeUserData)).DoesNothing();

    MwbeUserService userService = new MwbeUserService(mockedUserRepository, mockedNotificationService);

    //Act
    MwbeUser user = userService.AddUser(userRegistrationIn);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(user);            
    Assert.AreEqual(userRegistrationIn.Email, user.Email);
    Assert.AreEqual(userRegistrationIn.UserName, user.UserName);
    Assert.AreEqual(userRegistrationIn.FirstName,user.FirstName);
    Assert.AreEqual(userRegistrationIn.SecondName, user.SecondName);
    Assert.AreEqual(userRegistrationIn.BirthDate, user.BirthDate);

    A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Get(userRegistrationIn.UserName)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
    A.CallTo(() => mockedUserRepository.Save(ref mwbeUserData)).MustHaveHappened(Repeated.Exactly.Once);
}
```

UPDATE 1:

Please notice that for both calls to this method Save, value of mwbeUserData is the same

```
MwbeUserData mwbeUserData = mwbeReturnData.Data;
```

If this is null (but it's not).

Maybe the is problem with syntax for REF parameter?  I read that there should be used method called **AssignsOutAndRefParameters**, but I dont know exactly how to use it.

For now I will use MATCHES parameter to make it more generic.

Comment: I believes that it's occurred because you assert against `mwbeUserData` instance... Please add the code of `AddUser` method..

Comment: please add the `AddUser` implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believes that it's occurred because you assert against mwbeUserData instance

@Old Fox has the right of it.

You're asking FakeItEasy if `mockedUserRepository.Save(ref mwbeUserData)` was called with `null` input (`mwbeUserData` must be null at the time you make the check). It saw nothing like that, since the `MwbeUserData` that was passed to `mockedUserRepository.Save` inside `AddUser` appears to have been not null.

If you think the test should've passed, perhaps relaxing your constraint will help, as in [FakeItEasy: mocked method is not returning expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067284/fakeiteasy-mocked-method-is-not-returning-expected-result).

Also, note that the `ref`ness of the parameter has no effect on this behaviour. the same constraint matching would occur for a "plain" parameter. Only `out` parameters are exempted by default. See [Argument Constraints](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/argument-constraints/) in the FakeItEasy documentation for more information about this, and more on how to use custom argument matchers.

Comment: At Blair Conraid: I understand your idea, because it was my first post about FakeItEasy :)

Comment: Nice answer +1, this is what I thought in the first look but then I read again the question and I saw the exception, based on the exception there are 4 options: 1.in `AddUser` the OP initialize a new instance which he saves(if so he has a bug, the code should throw Null Reference...). 2.in `AddUser` the OP do null validation before he saves the object. 3.Special flow in `AddUser`. 4. I need a new glasses :) So we need the `AddUser` implementation to figure out the correct reason.